# Get Display Name for License SKU in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, displayname-attribute

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph to capture the products which we have licenses for.
While I can get the skupartname, that name is not exactly display-friendly.

I have come across **DisplayName** as a datapoint in almost all the API calls that give out an object with an id.

I was wondering if there was a **DisplayName** for the skus, and where I could go to get them via the graph.

For reference, the call I made was on the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus` endpoint following the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

The following is what's returned (after filtering out things I don't need), and as mentioned before, while I have a unique identifier which I can use via the **skuPartNumber**, that is not exactly PRESENTABLE.
You might notice for some of the skus, it difficult to figure out what it is referring to based on the names in the image of the Licenses page posted after the output

```
[
    {
        "capabilityStatus":  "Enabled",
        "consumedUnits":  0,
        "id":  "aca06701-ea7e-42b5-81e7-6ecaee2811ad_2b9c8e7c-319c-43a2-a2a0-48c5c6161de7",
        "skuId":  "2b9c8e7c-319c-43a2-a2a0-48c5c6161de7",
        "skuPartNumber":  "AAD_BASIC"
    },
    {
        "capabilityStatus":  "Enabled",
        "consumedUnits":  0,
        "id":  "aca06701-ea7e-42b5-81e7-6ecaee2811ad_df845ce7-05f9-4894-b5f2-11bbfbcfd2b6",
        "skuId":  "df845ce7-05f9-4894-b5f2-11bbfbcfd2b6",
        "skuPartNumber":  "ADALLOM_STANDALONE"
    },
    {
        "capabilityStatus":  "Enabled",
        "consumedUnits":  96,
        "id":  "aca06701-ea7e-42b5-81e7-6ecaee2811ad_0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52",
        "skuId":  "0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52",
        "skuPartNumber":  "MCOMEETADV"
    }
]
```

[image]

**Edit:** 
I am aware that I can get "friendly names" of SKUs in the following link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference

The problem is that it contains ONLY the 70ish most COMMON SKUs (in the last financial quarter), NOT ALL.
My organization alone has 5 SKUs not present on that page, and some of our clients for who we are an MSP for, also have a few. In that context, the link really does not solve the problem, since it is not reliable, nor updated fast enough for new SKUs

Answer (score 4):

You can see a match list from [Product names and service plan identifiers for licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference).

Please note that:

> the table lists the most commonly used Microsoft online service
>   products and provides their various ID values. These tables are for
>   reference purposes and are accurate only as of the date when this
>   article was last updated. Microsoft does not plan to update them for
>   newly added services periodically.

Here is an extra [list](https://github.com/directorcia/Office365/blob/master/o365-skus.ps1) which may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I will just parse this list, for my daily license autoreports. I really was hoping for something programmatic that was kept up to date in the API though. Regardless, thank you very much

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: It is helpful, I was hoping if there was something more programatic and better, since a number of my skus are not in that list, so I cant use it as a source to extract friendly names for my autogenerated report

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSV download available of the data on the ["Product names and service plan identifiers for licensing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference) page now.

For example, the current CSV (as of the time of posting this answer) is located at https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/3/e/e3e9faf2-f28b-490a-9ada-c6089a1fc5b0/Product%20names%20and%20service%20plan%20identifiers%20for%20licensing%20v9_22_2021.csv. This can be downloaded, cached and parsed in your application to resolve the product display name.

This is just a CSV format of the same table that is displayed on the webpage, which is not comprehensive, but it should have many of the products listed. If you find one that is missing, you can use the "Submit feedback for this page" button on the bottom of the page to create a GitHub issue. The documentation team usually responds in a few weeks.

Microsoft may provide an API for this data in the future, but it's only in their backlog. ([source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/81083#issuecomment-919579686))